# flying saucer page number + page count

Tags: flying-saucer

I'm trying to configure a nice footer on a pdf document I'm generating using Flying Saucer.
But I'm having problems getting the page number and page count in a nice position.

Consider this bit of css:

```
div#page-footer {
    position : running(footer);
    // ..  more styling .. //
}
div.page-number:before {
    content: counter(page);
}
```

Using this bit of html will not give me a page number:

```
<div id="page-footer">
    <div class="page-number"></div>
</div>
```

The only way I manage to get a page number if I move the class a level up.

```
<div id="page-footer" class="page-number">
</div>
```

But this does not allow me to add additional content in the footer or makes it really difficult to apply styling. I could add a separate footer just for the page number, but it would be quite hard to get the position just right.

Is there a way to get page number + page count in a footer that also contains other elements and styling?

Extra notes:

- I simplified the footer a bit, in the original there is more in there, but even this simple example it is giving problems.
- using span or div for the element does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `id` instead of the `class` to identify the div containing the page number.

This will work:

```
div#page-number:before {
    content: counter(page);
}

<div id="page-footer">
    <div id="page-number"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I tried this version, but apparently there was something else wrong when I tried that. Short feedback is this works. Bit annoying it has to be an id though, as I might want to use a similar footer for another section but with another page site/orientation. Anyway, implementing this. :).